# Suggestions on enforcing user count licensing on Windows domains

Tags: windows, licensing

We have an application that is inherently back-end (i.e. it runs on a server and users never interact with it directly).  The application interacts with file servers only via UNC shares (does not interact with SQL server or anything like that).

Our marketing folks want to sell this application based on the "number of users at the site" (or some other measure of the size of the customer), and have tasked me with figuring out a way to enforce this in our licensing system.

I know that Microsoft servers have CALs, and I'm wondering if there might be a way to query the domain controller to determine the CALs (so far, Googling has not turned up anything about this, though).

Does anyone have any clever or creative solutions for how to approach this?

Comment: I don't recall ever having to tell any of our servers how many CALs we owned.  (Except for Remote Desktop Server CALs, which are a bit different, but not everybody is going to be using them.)  If you're processing files created by the users, I suppose you could query the owner of each file and count the number of distinct accounts, but honestly any technical solution is going to be dodgy.  It's bad PR to show that you don't trust your customers (particularly in the enterprise market) but extra bad if you ever overcount, and there's bound to be some unexpected cases where that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Harry said, any solution you use will likely be dodgy because the number of users that you count will probably not reflect the number of users in reality. That being said, the best solution I can think of would be to count the number of enabled user objects within the Active Directory domain. This can be accomplished by using scripting languages or built-in commands:

PowerShell

```
(get-aduser -Filter {enabled -eq $true}).count
```

DSQuery

```
dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -limit 0 | find /v /c ""
```

VBScript

```
Const Ads_Scope_SubTree = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = Ads_Scope_SubTree 

objCommand.CommandText = _
"Select Name From 'LDAP://DC = [Your Domain], DC = Com' Where objectCategory = 'Person'" 

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
MsgBox "Total Number Of Users Found : " & objRecordSet.RecordCount
```

If you want to see what this looks like on steroids, please see https://4kib.com/export-active-directory-users/.